# How to secure messaging system like RabbitMQ/MQTT for use in a mobile application?

Tags: security, mobile, rabbitmq, messaging, mqtt

Let's say I want to write a mobile chat application (just as an example).

**How to receive only the messages meant for one client and don't let other clients receive messages which where not meant for them!?**

- Create a temp queue only known to the client? - *Secure enough?*
- Encrypting the message with clients public key? - *Own PKI needed!*
- Restrict access to queues based on some credentials the client sends with every request? - *Every request needs to be authenticated!*
- ...?

**If a client sends a message to the outgoing queue, how to prevent other clients from reading the message directly out of the queue!?**

- Restricting access to write-only? - *Don't know if this is possible...*
- Encrypting the message? - *Own PKI needed!*
- ...?

I hope my question/problem is clear and I'm really looking forward to hear your ideas and best practices!

Thanks in advance!

//edit: So using a temp queue for every client with encrypted messages might be a good choice. Or do you have any other ideas???

Comment: "Encrypting the message with clients public key?" - And have each client download *all* messages to see if there's one destined for itself?

Comment: No! Each client would still have its own queue, but encrypting would prevent other users/clients/hackers from reading messages they shouldn't read.

Answer (score 2):

If you use RabbitMQ AMQP broker, then you can use [Validated User-ID extension](https://www.rabbitmq.com/validated-user-id.html) power, but you have to create separate users for each client.

Using per-client queue maybe a good choice, but you have to realize that it "security through obscurity" and it smells. But as you suggested, message encryption may fix that.

You can play with [Access Control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) but you may find better to have some server application to handle complex user management things and use it api from clients for better user policies management.

Comment: Maybe combining per-client queue with encrypted messages would be a good choice. Or what do you think?

Comment: It really depends on your needs, but looks good for me (I've noted that with my recent edit).

Comment: Just a quick advise, queue per client gets cumbersome when the number of clients grow